# How to stop Ubuntu Mate hibernating when the battery hits zero

Tags: battery, ubuntu-mate, low-power

I sadly own an old IBM think pad x31 and its battery is shot. It only holds about 20% of its charge and more importantly the majority of its power is reported as being below zero percent. I recently upgraded from Lubuntu to Ubuntu mate. 
Lubuntu used to let it carry on until the battery decided it wanted to stop but Ubuntu mate always wants to hibernate when it hits zero. This is more frustrating as the laptop refuses to restore from hibernation and I have to reboot it twice to get it back to the desktop. 
I've already tried all the things already on this forum concerning using dconf-editor to change the values and to make it shutdown instead but none of this has any effect on the system. 
I'll be getting a new laptop soon but I really need this to tide me over until then.

TL;DR:
I need to try and stop any interference from Ubuntu mate concerning low battery actions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Control Center - Power management - On Battery Power**.
[image]

When battery power is critically low: **Do nothing**. (or **Shutdown**)

Comment: I did that and it still hibernated at 0%. I'll try again when I run it down next time but I'm not too hopeful